# unable to capture dynamic value from the response in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

unable to capture guid from the below respose using regular expression

{"failure":[],"success":{"NativeMobile.CheckoutItem":["46724846133980208"]}}

using below regular expression, tried with different options

NativeMobile.CheckoutItem":["(.*?)"]

Please help to get the guid from above response

Answer (score 0):

- The response seems to be [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)
- [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language)

I think it would be much easier to use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) instead, the relevant JsonPath query would be something like:

```
success.['NativeMobile.CheckoutItem'][0]
```

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)